# Drop Down Validation for entire column using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and trying to data validate for the data in an entire column. Using the below code for executing this.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("O:O").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=data_validation!N2:N340"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

With this code, I am able to get drop down for every cell in the column selected but the values in the drop down is getting removed one by one in every corresponding cells. For example if in list, I have values [1,2,3,4,5]. In the first cell drop down, I will have the option to select [1,2,3,4,5]. In 2nd cell drop down,I am getting the option to select [2,3,4,5] and so on.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have entered the validation formula as a relative reference, therefore for each successive cell the validation range is offset by 1 row..  So, enter the formula as an absolute reference

```
=data_validation!$N$2:$N$340
```